# Controlling a 12V coil using a 3.3V MCU

Tags: microcontroller, driver, coil

I am trying to design a driver circuit for a coil that I am planning to use as an electromagnet. The coil is rated at 12V @ 3A. The part number is [FC-6521](https://apwelectromagnets.com/fc-6521.html#product-details-tab-specification).

The MCU will output a 3.3V through GPIO (~20mA). I have simulated a design shown below:

[image]

The transistor and diode I chose were parts that I own just to make it easier for me to test. I am not very familiar with the resistor values that I need. Can I get some advice for what I need to change? Thanks!

Comment: R2 is superfluous... D1 is under-rated.. needs to handle your full coil current..5A device would be preferred.

Comment: @Trevor R2 isn't superfluous. Without R2 the MOSFET would never turn off.

Comment: @MarkoBuršič, riiight, in this test circuit you are correct, it needs a gate drain, but I meant when driving it from the MCU.

Comment: @Trevor I know, but you should mention that MCU output  should me sinking type or push/pull.

Comment: True enough @MarkoBuršič, sinking type would need a pull-up on the gate.

Comment: A weak pull down is good to ensure no problems with a floating pin while the mcu is initializing.

Comment: Yes @passerby good point, but 75% divider just heats up the Mosfet

Comment: @Trevor: I think by "weak" he was implying using a much higher value resistor than the pretty strong 300R pull down.

Comment: 1k to 10k for both is pretty sufficient. A mosfet is a voltage driven device and it shouldn't need 20mA to turn on.  The gate voltage may be a bigger concern. Not sure if this is a 3.3V logic level mosfet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With MOSFETs, one of the important design parameters is how much gate voltage is needed to turn the device on.

This particular device is not being driven very hard with only 3.3V on the gate.  It's probably fine at 3A, though.  R1 is okay, but R2 is way too small.  It's not needed while the gate is actively driven; it's there for ensuring the device is off when the driving circuit is in an un-powered state. You want the gate to be close to 3.3V, so around 10k ohms would be better.

And like someone noted above, D1 is too small.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into a different MOSFET that fits this design better. Maybe a logic level MOSFET.

Answer (score 0):

The [MOSFET datasheet](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf3709pbf.pdf?fileId=5546d462533600a4015355df8536193f) Fig 3 shows a maximum on resistance of $$ {15~V\over70~A} =  210~m\Omega .$$

The power dissipation will be 2 W and seems that you are in a safe area.

(Watch out for the 2.7 V and 20 \$\mu\$s pulse widths shown in Figure 1 and Figure 2.  :-)

The 300 \$\Omega\$ resistor must be omitted to ensure as large as possible voltage on the gate.

Comment: Figure 3 is for the saturation region, where you don't want to be operating if using the MOSFET as a switch.  Data sheet gives Rdson  as 10.5 mohm max with 4.5V on the gate. This will increase at lower gate voltage and elevated temperature, but not anywhere near 210 mohm

Comment: @user28910 bud when we use a MOSFET as a switch we want it saturated with as low on resistance as possible.  See [Chapter 2 - Saturation region](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/transistor/tran_7.html) of this or any other good article on the web.  (Because MOSFETs are majority carrier devices they switch off fast even when in 'deep' saturation.  Transistors in 'deep' saturation have a switch-off delay because it takes a relatively long time for the carriers to be removed from the base region. :-)

Comment: Keep in mind that 'Saturation' means one thing when referring to a bipolar transistor and a different thing when referring to a field-effect transisitor. In the linked article, the figure 'MOSFET Characteristic Curves' correctly indicates the saturation region, the region to the right of the green dashed line.  But below, section 2 titled 'Saturation Region' refers to the region to the left of that line, which is properly called the Ohmic Region, sometimes called the Linear Region.

Comment: Still, hard on is preferred when using MOSFET switching.